# How to use the correct version of python (OSX)?

Tags: python, macos, allennlp

I have the following version of python installed.

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
$ which python2
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
```

allennlp is installed here.

```
$ which allennlp
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/allennlp
```

But when I run allennlp. It obviously used python version 2. I don't want to manually edit allennlp or make a new symlink of python pointing to python3.

```
$ echo "The cryptocurrency space is now figuring out to have the highest search on Google globally ." > sentences.txt
$ echo "Bitcoin alone has a sixty percent share of global search ." >> sentences.txt
$ allennlp elmo sentences.txt elmo_layers.hdf5
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named allennlp
```

Does anybody know what is the best way to deal with this case? Thanks.

Comment: How did you install allennlp? If it wasn't via `pip`, you probably just need to uninstall it, then reinstall it with `pip3`. If it's a properly-written package, it'll then install an entry-point that shbangs the right Python.

Comment: If the package is broken and creates wrong entry-point scripts, you can report a bug upstream, but meanwhile, you'll have to either manually edit the script it creates, or write an bash alias or something that explicitly calls `python3 $(which allennlp)` or the like.

Comment: Or you may want to consider setting up a virtualenv, installing into that, and then writing a launcher or alias that does something like `activate allennlp && allennlp`.

Comment: I tried both `pip` and `pip3`. They all give errors. So it sounds an bug in allennlp? $ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
$ pip3 --version
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: I got this error. ````python3 "$(which allennlp)" elmo sentences.txt elmo_layers.hdf5
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/allennlp", line 1
    python -m allennlp.run "$@"
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Hold on, your setup is much more confusing than you originally let on. You have both 3.6 and 3.7, and somehow your `pip` is for 3.6 but your `pip3` is for 3.7, your `python` is for one of your two 2.7s, and your `python3` is for 3.7? Once you get into a situation like that, you really can't just run bare `python` and `pip`, or even `python3` and `pip3`, and expect them to work. You either need to be explicit everywhere, or use virtualenvs.

Comment: You can try `python3.6 $(which allennlp)`. But I suspect you're going to need to reinstall something, possibly after some cleanup.